# check box validation javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I need to validate the selection of at least one check box on a table. I am not using an alert because I already have a class on CSS that highlights in red the inputs, selects and other elements if they are not filled out.

This is my JS:

```
var btnRegister= document.querySelector('#btnRegisterRegObr');

btnRegister.addEventListener('click', function () {

    var bError= false; 
    //I am initializing this boolean variable so that it also shows an error
    //message on the screen if the user has not selected any option at all...

    var elementCheckRegObr = document.querySelector('#checkRegObr');

    if (elementCheckRegObr.checked==false){

        bError=true;    
        elementCheckRegObr.classList.add('error'); 
        //This part of the code brings the error I have 
        //previously created on CSs if the checkbox is not checked

    }
    else{
        elementCheckRegObr.classList.remove('error');
    }
});
```

The button on HTML has the right id on the HTML: id="btnRegisterRegObr.

I was looking at some codes here and people were validating using the .checked==false

However this does not seem to work for mine.

As a matter of fact, I first thought I needed to use the syntax of if (elementCheckRegObr.checked=="") but that one does not seem to work either.

I dont have problems validating inputs, selects nor radio buttons, but I am not sure if I am doing it on the right way with the check boxes. Any help or advice would be greatly apprecciate it :)

Comment: could you make a fiddle of it ? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what do you mean by fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use getElementById to get your elements, and test if the checkbox is checked this way:

```
if(document.getElementById('idOfTheCheckBox').checked){
 alert('hey, im checked!');
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help!

I just checked as you just instructed and that seems to be working fine. Now if I want to show the error when the boxes are not checked, I used the same syntax but adding this: ....('idOfTheCheckBox').checked==false) and that also seems to be working fine :)

My problem now is that the only way that is working is with the alert message, but when I add the error that I have on CSS, nothing seems to change.

This is what I have on CSS for the error class:
.error{
    border: 1px solid #c0392b;
}